# Issue in sending emails with Content Hub OOTB Email Template

Tags: content-hub, content-hub-scripting

Anyone tried sending emails using `Content Hub OOTB Email Template` through action scripts?

It is behaving very strange to me, If I add my personal email in recipient list, it is sending an email to me but it is also sending that email to all the users created in my content hub instance.

Is it expected behavior?

Content Hub version : 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a sitecore ticket for that and they suggested me to use `username` instead of `email id`. The system should then be able to fetch the email from the user's profiles, it worked and it sent email to only that particular user.

But if you add any wrong `username` which doesn't exist in content hub or add `email id` which is not a user name then it sent that email to all the users created in my content hub instance.

**`Sitecore accepted this as a known issue and that has been fixed in Content Hub 4.2.2.`**

The reference is MONE-32071:

https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/users/42/content-hub/release-notes--04-02-02--resolved-issues.html

To workaround the issue you could:

- Make sure that at least one usernames in the recipient list is valid
- Upgrade to the latest Content Hub release

**Update-1**

***If you want to know more about how to send email notifications in Content Hub please follow my below blog post.***

https://logicalmindscom.wordpress.com/2023/06/19/sending-email-notifications-in-sitecore-content-hub/

Comment: this is helpful, thanks for sharing!

Comment: Please upvote if you think this is helpful, it might help others also.

Comment: please share more details for the users as we are able to send emails to specific users and not the whole list from CH. you can also send it to the user who has created the Assets. If you share more details will help to answer.

Comment: Thanks @Nikhil Kulkarni for your feedback. Updated my answer and referenced a blog for this.